# Save json request to a file

Tags: python, web-scraping, web

thanks for your attention!

I'm doing a for loop and "requesting url" here on python and getting a "json" response, want to add all the loops to a file to read later on excel, or other json reader...

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    url = f"https://api.xxx.com.br/ecommerce-web/api/parceiro/meuCadastro/{x}/true"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

So after this loop I got 5 responses like this

```
{'A': 1, 'Name': 'Name01'}
{'A': 2, 'Name': 'Name02'}
{'A': 3, 'Name': 'Name03'}
{'A': 4, 'Name': 'Name04'}
{'A': 5, 'Name': 'Name05'}
```

And i want to do a json file with all that answers, thank you guys! I'm just starting on webscraping.

Solve this problem add all the answers on json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in json library to write json files.

```py
import json

data = []  # save all responses here

for x in range(1, 6):
    url = f"https://api.xxx.com.br/ecommerce-web/api/parceiro/meuCadastro/{x}/true"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data.append(response.json())  # append every json response


with open("myjson.json", "w") as file:  # "w" will create myjson.json if it doesn't exist, otherwise rewrite the whole file
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)  # dump all the data into the json file with 4 space indentation
```

Comment: So useful answer, works like a charm

Comment: Can I create a csv file to make a excel readable data too? thanks!!!!!!

Comment: yup you can, using the `csv` standard library of python, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)